# Set nav bar to only fade in on home page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Using Bootstrap 3, on rails. My goal is to have the nav bar fade in upon scrolling (working fine) but also display without scrolling when the page is too short to scroll. OR to display only on the home page. The latter is preferred, but either will solve my issue.

My (working) JS.

```
(function ($) {
      $(document).ready(function(){

        // hide .navbar first
        $(".navbar").hide();

        // fade in .navbar
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {

                     // set distance user needs to scroll before we start fadeIn
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('.navbar').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('.navbar').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        });

    });
      }(jQuery))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a class 'home' or anything to a  tag and call the same function.

```
<body class="home"></body>
<script>
    if ($('body').hasClass('home')) {
        $('.navbar').fadeIn();
        } else {
        $('.navbar').fadeOut();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems silly but.. Just check the pathname?

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/myhomepageurlregex/)){
    $('.navbar').fadeIn();
}
```

myhomepageurlregex is whatever your homepage url happens to be, can match part of it if need be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly show the navbar on only one page, why don't you just put a  tag into the ERB for that page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.navbar').fadeIn();
</script>
```